# Batch - Look for specific usb device

Tags: batch-file, cmd, usb-drive

what im trying to approach is to make batch check if there is a specific usb device, not flash disks, but a specific game controller, I found some wmic commands, and they work, but not in way i want, since i need raw true / false, I attempted to catch command result from wmic but unsuccessfully. Here is my wmic command: `wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where CAPTION="PLAYSTATION(R)3 Controller" get /value`, thanks for any help

Comment: Are you looking at the installed field? This is currently unclear.

Comment: `GET` what? Which property do you want.

Comment: @Mark I need to get true / false return to know if controller is connected or not

Comment: What do you mean by installed field? @GerhardBarnard

Comment: `wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where CAPTION="ACPI Fan" get /format:list   | FindStr /C:Present=TRUE` and as a second line `echo %errorlevel%` 0 = exist and 1 = not exist.

Comment: @Mark can I use that sentence twice but with different caption in single batch file?

Comment: Of course; why couldn't you?